# Assign url to wsgi gunicorn server

Tags: python, flask, url, web-applications, plotly-dash

This may seem like a stupid question but I'm very new to web development so please bear with me.

I have created a dash web app that I am deploying with a wsgi server, and I can't for the life of me find any information on how to actually assign a url to the ip address.

For example, if I follow this tutorial - https://kevalnagda.github.io/flask-app-with-wsgi-and-nginx

I can get the app running on `http://localhost:80` easily, but I cannot seem to find how to assign it with a unique url. Something like `www.mywebapp.com`. Is there a substantial piece of this I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buy a domain name and then go to the registrar and add your hosting server's public IP. Basically, unless you're willing to self-host, then you need to buy a server and run your code on it. The company you buy the server from will give you a public IP (or you could use your own and port-forward, google "what is my ip"). Then enter that into your registrar after buying the domain and completing the necessary verification steps and then you should get a domain name.

Hope that helps.